# Gradle Build failed in Jhipster

Tags: java, gradle, jhipster, java-13

I want to build my project in jhipster but now i got this error (I installed recently jdk 13 ). 
my IDE: VISUAL STUDIO **

does anyone have an idea?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file `/Users/bensalemwassim/Desktop/TAC-PROJECT/tour-area-calculation/build.gradle`
- What went wrong:

```
 startup failed:
 General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57

 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
     at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:184)
     at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
      (...)

   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)`

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: is the java13 added to your PATH, i.e. what's the output of `java -version` from cmd? And did you setup the IDE to use 13?

Comment: openjdk 13.0.2 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing) 

how can i know if its addded to my path or not? and how to setup the IDE?

Comment: You need Gradle 6.0 or higher for Java 13. Are you using that?

Comment: @BjørnVester: actual JHipster generator uses gradle 6.0.1 wrapper (see e.g.: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gradle/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties)

Comment: Does the build work from the commandline?